# Iterating over an array and adding together odd numbers while anything that isn't a number

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to write a loop that loops through an array, identifies if the value is a number, then checks if it is an odd number, and if it is then adds the odd number to oddTotal.

```
function addOdds(numArray) {
  //implement this function
    var oddTotal = 0
    for (var i=0; i < numArray.length; i++) {      //this iterates through the array
    if (numArray[i] !== typeof(value)) {
      i++
    }
    else if (numArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {          //this checks if the number value is odd (assuming that it is a number value)   
      oddTotal += numArray[i];
      }
      }

 return oddTotal;
    }
  
var numArray = [1, 11, 20, 21, 30, 'fat'];
console.log (addOdds(numArray));
```

My function works if I assume that all values are numbers, but isn't able to ignore any other data types.

Comment: What do you think does `numArray[i] !== typeof(value)` do? Please read the documentation on [`typeof`](//developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof).

Answer (score 0):

I used Number.isInteger and that solution worked!

```
function addOdds(numArray) {
  //implement this function
    var oddTotal = 0; 
    for (var i=0; i < numArray.length; i++) {      //this iterates through the array
    
    //this checks if the number value is odd (assuming that it is a number value AND if the number is an integer)   
    if (numArray[i] % 2 !== 0 && Number.isInteger(numArray[i])  ) { 
      oddTotal += numArray[i];
      }
      }

 return oddTotal;
    }
  
var numArray = [1, 11, 20, 21, 30, 'fat', ];
console.log (addOdds(numArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if each array element is not an integer `! Number.isInteger(numArray[i])` or not a number `typeof numArray[i] !== 'number'`

```
function addOdds(numArray) {
    var oddTotal = 0
    for (var i=0; i < numArray.length; i++) {  
        if(! Number.isInteger(numArray[i])) {
            continue;
        } else if (numArray[i] % 2 !== 0) {
            oddTotal += numArray[i];
        }
    }

    return oddTotal;
}
  
var numArray = [1, 11, 20, 21, 30, 'fat'];
console.log (addOdds(numArray));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed with a reduce function for the above scenario:

```
numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,'js','abc'];

reducer = (sum, currentValue) => currentValue%2!=0 && !isNaN(currentValue) ? sum + currentValue : sum;

console.log(numbers.reduce(reducer,0));
```

The '0' is the initial sum value.